# Потери данных при записи аудио потоков (Linux 64bit)

Tags: аудио, потоки-данных, x86-64, c++, linux

Уважаемые профи! Написал программу записи нескольких потоков аудио данных с АЦП(специальная плата `PCI`). Программа работает, но при прослушивании записи слышны потери данных, причем достаточно большие... Пропадают куски слов или даже целые слова. Программа написана для `Linux 64 bit` (хотя писал в `Ubuntu 32bit`). Грешу на специфику 64 битной системы, но сам найти косяк не могу... Помогите разобраться. Заранее спасибо.
вот основные методы программы (без АЦП программа работать не будет):

```
 1. Метод вызывается из другого потока, beginPoint это unsigned int*
<code>

void *ThreadsManager::readThread(void *arg)
{
    CHECK;
    ThreadsManager *obj = static_cast<ThreadsManager*>(arg);
    int chan = obj->chan;
    int kadr = obj->kadr;
    int step = 0;
    int delta = 0;
    unsigned short *buffer = new unsigned short[32768];
    int silentCount = 0;
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
//  pthread_cleanup_push(obj->exitHandler, (void*)obj);
    while (1)
    {
        while (delta < 64 * 2)
        {
            usleep(100);
            delta = (posPoint[I_ADC_PCI_COUNT_L791] >= (kadr + chan) * 4) ?
                    (posPoint[I_ADC_PCI_COUNT_L791] - (kadr + chan) * 4) : (obj->size - (kadr + chan) * 4 + posPoint[I_ADC_PCI_COUNT_L791]);
        }CHECK;
        buffer[step] =
                (unsigned short)((beginPoint[kadr + chan] & 0xFFFF) << 2);
        step += 1;
        if (step == 32768)
        {
            obj->writeData(buffer, step, chan);
            fprintf(stderr, "write %i byte of data\n",  strlen((char*)buffer));
            memset(buffer, 0, step * 2);
            step = 0;
        }
        if ((chan < 8) && (!chanChecker[chan]))
        {
            obj->writeData(buffer, step, chan);
            fprintf(stderr, "write %i byte of data (button off)\n",
                    strlen((char*)buffer));
            memset(buffer, 0, step * 2);
            step = 0;
            break;
        }
        else if (abs((int)beginPoint[kadr + chan]) < 200)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "->for analog channel...\n");
            if ((silentCount += 1) == 100)
            {
                obj->writeData(buffer, step, chan);
                memset(buffer, 0, step * 2);
                step = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            silentCount = 0;
        if ((kadr += 16) == obj->size / 4) kadr = 0;
        CHECK;
        usleep(100);
    }
    obj->saveToWav(obj->rate, chan);
    obj->threadBusy[chan] = false;
    delete[] buffer;
    CHECK;
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    pthread_exit(0);
//          pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
    return NULL;
}

</code>

 2. Метод записи в файл:
```

<code>

```
 int FileManager::writeData(unsigned short *ptr, int size, int chanNo)
    {
        CHECK;
        if (!outFileArray[chanNo].is_open())
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "->error: file for channel %i was not opened\n",
                    chanNo);
            return -1;
        }
        outFileArray[chanNo].write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ptr), size * 2);
        return 0;
    }
```

</code>

```
 3. На всякий случай, метод, который вызывает readThread:
```

<code>

```
 void *DeviceAPI::detectThreadFunc(void *arg)
    {
        CHECK;
        int channel = 0;
        int kadr = 0;
        int delta = 0;
        DeviceAPI *obj = static_cast<DeviceAPI*>(arg);
        unsigned short *tmp = new unsigned short[1];
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
        while (1)
        {
            CHECK;
            obj->getTTL();
            while (delta < 64 * 2)
            {
                usleep(100);
                delta = (posPoint[I_ADC_PCI_COUNT_L791] >= (kadr + channel) * 4) ?
                        (posPoint[I_ADC_PCI_COUNT_L791] - (kadr + channel) * 4) :
                        (obj->size - (kadr + channel) * 4
                                + posPoint[I_ADC_PCI_COUNT_L791]);
            }
            if (!obj->chanBusy(channel) && chanChecker[channel] && (channel < 8))
            {
                CHECK;
                obj->startRead(channel, kadr);
                usleep(1000);
            }
            else if (!obj->chanBusy(channel) && (channel > 8))
            {
                CHECK;
                tmp[0] = (unsigned short)(beginPoint[kadr + channel] & 0xFFFF);
                if (abs(tmp[0]) > 50)
                {
                    obj->startRead(channel, kadr);
                    usleep(1000);
                }
            }
            if ((channel += 1) == 16)
            {
                channel = 0;
                if ((kadr += 16) == obj->size / 4) kadr = 0;
            }CHECK;
        }
        delete []tmp;
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
        pthread_exit(0);
        CHECK;
        return NULL;
    }
```

</code>

Блин форматирование не работает?
Все, жду ваших советов... Спасибо.

Comment: Без форматирования вообще не айс смотреть на код=). Попробуйте clangовским статическим анализатором провериться и поправте все варнинги.

Comment: Используй кнопочку {} для форматирования кода.

Comment: Поправил, спасибо... Думал <code></code> будет работать, ан нет...

Comment: Прогонял через cppcheck все косяки исправлены. Пару ворнингов осталось, но они не существенны.

Comment: Проблема не решена, к сожалению.

Comment: я правильно понимаю что тут не испоьзуется ни dma ни драйвер ? напишите лучше к вашей карточке драйвер alsa нормальный и записывайте стандартными писалками.

Comment: К сожалению, плата АЦП использует свой собственный драйвер, который в свою очередь использует DMA и BUSMastering, так что alsa отпадает. А жаль, это оочень упростило бы задачу...